# Get connection to Trace32 running on Host-PC using t32apinet.dll on Remote-PC

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, trace32, lauterbach

I'm try to use *t32apinet.dll* on *host V* (Win7 embedded 32bit) to connect with *host W* (Win 7 64bit).
TRACE32 on *host W* is already configured in *config.t32* to accept a connection:

```
; Remote Control Access
RCL=NETASSIST
PORT=20000
PACKLEN=1024
```

TRACE32 is running on *W* while I try to config the driver and to establish the connection from *V* as follows:

```
T32 = new T32API();
T32.Config("NODE=", "192.168.100.2");//all Config returns 0 (no errors)
T32.Config("PACKLEN=", "1024");
T32.Config("PORT=", "20000");

T32.Init();//returns -1

//T32.Attach((int) T32API.Device.ICD);
```

On *W* I see incoming packages on port 20000 when Init() is executed on *V*.

Any ideas why Init() return with error?

Additional info regarding comments bellow:

- I'm using *T32Start*-Tool to start *Trace32*, where using of API Port is activated and *port value: 20000* is set
- calling *t32remtest.exe 192.168.100.2 port=20000* on remote PC returns:

  ```
  error initializing TRACE32 
  error initializing TRACE32
  ```

Comment: Does it work if TRACE32 and your .NET-client are running on the same host? Can you connect to your TRACE32 instance with the command line tool t32rem.exe (which also uses the remote API) ?

Comment: @Holger didn't know there are this tools, thank you for hint!
calling on remote machine I just get (same?) error:  

`d:\Lauterbach\bin\windows>t32remtest.exe 192.168.100.2`
`port=20000`
`error initializing TRACE32`
`error initializing TRACE32`
  
same call on localhost brings me a prompt CMD>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although I saw the incoming packages in the sniffer there was no reactions from TRACE32.

The problem was that Windows recognized that network as *public* and blocked packages on the application level. Due to specific local IT policies the solution for me is to create a rule in windows firewall to explicitly allow communication on UDP port 20000:
[screen with settings for new inbound rule in Win firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crQio.png)

Answer (score 0):

The minimum viable settings block for enabling the Remote API port of TRACE32 in your configuration file is:

```
RCL=NETASSIST
PORT=20000
```

Please make sure to **include an empty line before and after the block** and that the correct TRACE32 configuration file is selected during start-up.

If you are using the *T32Start* utility to start TRACE32, the configuration file gets dynamically generated and is not necessarily identical with the default one *config.t32*.

Comment: there are empty lines before and after the block in _config.t32_. But I'm using _T32Start_, so which setting here will allow the remote access? _API Port use_ is set to _yes_ with same value _20000_